# Not fetching result into Array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have my data in MySQL database is

'1', 'Demo', 'Demo1', 'Test'

On line 'echo $row[2]' it gives error "Notice: Undefined offset: 2"

Any solutions..?? PHP Code is as below...

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

    $uname=$_POST['txtUserName'];
    $passwd=$_POST['txtPassword']; 

    $query="SELECT usernm,passwd FROM tbuserdemo WHERE usernm='$uname'";
    $result=  mysql_query($query);
    $rows=  mysql_num_rows($result); 

    if($rows==0)
    {
        echo "User Name is Wrong";
    }
    else
    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
        $encpasswd=  encrypt(1, $passwd);        


        if ($row[1]==$encpasswd)
        {            
            echo "Welcome $uname";
            echo $row[2];
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Password is Wrong";
        }
    }


    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: **Your code is vunarable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).** Please take care of that before using this code in a live environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only fetching 2 fields from the database, `SELECT usernm,passwd` so you should only have `$row[0]` and `$row[1]` with values. Array indexes are zero-based.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to programming. Many languages do this, Array indexes start at `0` NOT `1`. So you need to do

```
if ($row[0]==$encpasswd)
        {            
            echo "Welcome $uname";
            echo $row[1];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be `$row[0]` and `$row[1]`. Remember, PHP's arrays are zero-based. To get a $row[2] you'd have to be selecting **THREE** fields in your query.

Answer (score 0):

change to this :

```
   if ($row[0]==$encpasswd)
    {            
        echo "Welcome $uname";
        echo $row[1];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Password is Wrong";
    }
}


?>
```

first index in the array is in location 0 (not 1)

Answer (score 0):

The arrays begin with 0.

Try this:

```
    if ($row[0]==$encpasswd)
    {            
        echo "Welcome $uname";
        echo $row[1];
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Password is Wrong";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read up a bit on [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) attacks. At least if you intend to publish that code outside a development/testing environment.